# Steps to backup a linux disk using dd needed

Tags: linux, disk-image, ubuntu-18.04

So after much research, I just need a couple of things clarified I don't fully understand about dd just yet.

I want to do a full disk image backup of an Ubuntu 18.04 linux disk ( a 500GB SSD ) into a single backup file on a separate portable external USB hard disk.

This will be a full image of the Ubuntu 18.04 linux disk, not file copy.

The idea is that if the existing disk dies, we can just replace the dead disk, run dd again to re-image the disk using the single backup file on the portable external USB hard disk we took previously. I like the idea of a file as its portable and possibly smaller than a full image.

A couple of questions :

1. I've read that its a good idea to have the server we are backing up shut down so the disk we are copying from is not active, so I am assuming this would require running dd from a bootable USB - is this correct and how exactly would I make such a bootable USB with dd on it please?
2. Will dd make a complete image of the disk - e.g. back up the MBR and any hidden partitions etc on the linux SSD disk, and how would we make sure these are copied off?
3. How do we make sure the bootable USB has all the drivers to recognize both the disk we are backing up, and the external USB hard disk that we are writing the disk image to?
4. What sort of size would we need for the portable USB hard drive that the backup file will sit on? Can we get maybe a 2:1 compression or if its a 500GB drive will we need a 500 GB drive to backup to?

Comment: Why `dd`? Why not Rsync?

Comment: I'm newish to linux, which is why I'm asking what might seem like "obvious" questions. Hopefully trying to learn doesnt mean being downvoted... I'm not lazy, just need specific answers that I havent been able to find.

Comment: @steve Unfortunately, around here, it often does mean being downvoted.  Which is why I upvoted your good question.  You performed prior research, and you are asking good questions.  The only possible issue is that you are asking multiple questions at once.  But the downvoting started with nobody offering to help you by  mentioning that issue.  My recommendation is to break up this question into multiple questions.  Others should have made this recommendation instead of downvoting.

Comment: Hi End, thank you, appreciate the feedback about the questions :-)  Happy to post back updates to help the community here....

Comment: have you considered perhaps using a more full-featured application like clonezilla (just as example)? it is entirely possible to roll-your-own using DD and a custom USB disk and whatnot, and if you are just learning/studying then that's fine, but long term reliability is a problem if you are wanting a real-world solution .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "I've read that its a good idea to have the server we are backing up shut down so the disk we are copying from is not active." Not just a "good idea*, but required. Windows has [Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/volume-shadow-copy-service) that takes a snapshot of a drive that is in use, allowing copying of a mounted drive. Linux does not have VSS, yet.
2. There are any number of tools to make a boot disk that includes dd and other disk copying tools, such as [Ubuntu Live USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal), [Runtime Live USB](https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-live-cd.htm) and many [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/hiren39s-bootcd/?platform=linux). One can use virtually (no pun intended) *any* disk imaging tool, even one based on Win PE or Win RE.

   One can make the [Ubuntu Live USB](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started) on a Windows, MacOS or Linux box. The installation media thus created has all drivers needed to perform basic I/O and display on most PC's, and should be [able to image the server's internal drive to an external drive](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/create-disk-image-clone-hard-disk-partition-with-ubuntu-live-usb/). If you prefer a GUI for making that disk image, [the *Disks* utility](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/manage-ubuntu-hdd-disk-utility/), included on the Ubuntu Live media, can do so.

Comment: all good advice if you are needing to image a full system for restore or cloning, but I would point out that many folks don't backup systems, just their content (and perhaps configuration), and in that case none of this is necessary. if one is just interested in backing up file-content, then tools that work through the filesystem like `rsync` are a "simpler" approach, that don't require an offline state.

Comment: Thanks DrMoishe, I will post back on my findings/experience as I work through this activity.

Comment: @FrankThomas, 1. OP: "I want to do a **full disk image** backup." 2. While incremental backup is fine, there have been *many* questions here about what to do when an essential component was missed in backup. Full images avoid that (though I do trust compression, *if verified*). *Just* using file backup is even less trustworthy then a Windows "Restore Point".

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, yes of course. I'm just pointing out that its common in recent years to not backup full systems, just their content, and to use different technologies to spin up and configure new server instances, such that the server OS itself is disposable. this lets you get back to a steady-state at any time, rather than propagating any problems that have arisen on the server over time to the restored build. using dd is a down and dirty way to get an image for storage, but its just one tool in a chain as OP indicates, so the end-to-end process has lots of points for failure. thats all. +1.

Comment: @FrankThomas, yes a valid point. As an example, exporting a database to a new server, or even multiple servers, is far more efficient than cloning one server. And daily backup of that *can* be faster than imaging -- though an image made using direct drive I/O can be faster than backing up just some of the data. Each has its purpose.